# Does $0$ belong to the Lebesgue set of Heaviside function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Lebesgue set: For a function $f \in L^1_{\operatorname{loc}} (R^n)$ and $x \in R^n$, $x$ is said to be a point in the Lebesgue set of $f$ if there exists a number $A$ such that

$\lim_{r=0} 1/(\lambda(B(x,r)) \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)-A|dy = 0$.

Now if we consider $H$ to be the heaviside function

$H(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x > 0 , \\
1/2 & \text{if } x = 0, \\
0 & \text{if } x<0.
\end{cases}$

I have been able to show that $H(x) = \lim_{r=0} 1/2r \int_{x-r}^{x-r} H(y)dy$

But from this, it follows that $H(0) = 1/2$, and thus $0$ belongs in the lebesgue set. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have done nothing wrong, other than being a bit sloppy in the final paragraph (where you say “But from this, it follows that $H(0)=1/2$). That is, after all how you *defined* $H$. But yes, $0$ is indeed a Lebesgue point of $H$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen BUt the question actually asks me to show that 0 isn't a lebesgue point of the function. 
Will you please elaborate my sloppines ?

Comment: Oops, no, I take back what I said. Note the absolute value in the definition of Lebesgue point! I'll write a more complete answer in a moment. Sorry about my earlier mistake.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what $A$ is, one of $|0-A|\ge\frac12$ or $|1-A|\ge\frac12$ will hold. Therefore, $$\int_{-r}^r|H(x)-A|\,dx\ge\frac r2, \quad\text{and so}\quad \frac1{2r}\int_{-r}^r|H(x)-A|\,dx\ge \frac14. $$

Comment: Could you please elaborate further as to why one of the two would have to hold ?
and also tell me where are you getting these inequalities from ?

Comment: The first one: Just look at the number line, or use the triangle inequality to get $|A|+|1-A|\ge1$. If a sum is $\ge1$, at least one summand must be $\ge\frac12$. The integral inequality comes from restricting the interval of integration to $[0,r]$ if $|1-A|\ge\frac12$, or to $[-r,0]$ if $|A|\ge\frac12$.

Comment: Yes its clear now.